# Laravel 5 Login redirect to a subdomain

Tags: php, laravel-5

For my web application we have sub-domains for each account `account1.example.org & account2.example.org`. They all go to the same place just it allows us to have the account in the URL.

I have everything working with the sub-domains. My issue is with the Laravel 5 login code. I am unsure on how to get it to redirect to the sub-domain (which is stored in the DB and accessible by Auth::user()->account->sub_domain).

I have seen people try and change the action but not add to the address. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Define `route` -

```
Route::get(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function($account){
    // Process data or redirect
});
```

And after login -

```
Redirect::to('account1.myapp.com');
```

Comment: I would probably use a `Route::group` for the first part to encompass all the routes. However, where would the Redirect go to?

Comment: My current thinking is overriding the postLogin as I do with getRegister and change the links that way.

Comment: just add a method which will handle the request for those subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

So with the help from sgt BOSE, this is what I came up with.

In my `AuthController.php` I added

```
/**
 * Redirect Path
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function redirectPath()
{
    $redirectTo = property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';

    $url = Config::get('app.url');
    $subDomain = Auth::user()->account->sub_domain;
    $scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    return $scheme.'://'.$subDomain.'.'.$host.$redirectTo;
}
```

What this does is returns the link for the postLogin and postRegister. This method is only called when they are successful. The gets my sub-domain and builds a link based on the config item for my URL.

To make sure that the login worked I also had to change the domain item in `config/session.php` file. `'domain' => null -> 'domain' => '.example.org'`.